# Change Ctrl-D shortcut in GNU-Screen

Tags: linux, keyboard-shortcuts, gnu-screen

Can someone please help me change a shortcut in GNU Screen. I bound my Ctrl-D for escape, and now when I go into copy mode U is moving a screen up, however D isn't scrolling a page down. I can't seem to find information on how to change that shortcut. Help please.

Answer (score -1):

You need to install this tool using any one of the following command (Debian / Ubuntu Linux):
$ sudo apt-get install gconf-editor

Or if you are using Fedora / CentOS /RHEL Linux:

## yum install gconf-editor

Run gconf-editor

Use menus or type a command as follows:
$ gconf-editor &

Next double click the "apps" folder
Next double click the "metacity" folder
Finally click the global_keybindings folder